# How to prioritize values in multi picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, community, multi-select

Hi Friends i got a requirement like want to prioritize values in multi picklist. It means if they select more than one field i want to prioritize like S.no.

Now  i have sample picklist like.

[image: Present picklist]

I required like

[image: Required]

I don't have any clue is this possible.Because they want to prioritize but i didn't find any clue to work on this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible out of the box.

Of course there are other ways to do it, including complex logic in Visualforce and APEX. But also simpler ones. It all depends on your full set of requirements, also in reporting etc.

A simple example of what you could do is create multiple 'normal' picklists. E.g. create these 3:

-#1 Reason Lost

-#2 Reason Lost

-#3 Reason Lost

Each picklist will have the same 5 options. The end users can determine the priority for each reason, up until 3 different reasons (1 in each picklist, ordered by priority). You could add a validation rule that checks if they are all different.

Comment: They need for reporting purpose.If i add numbers with visual force page and apex above to the values in picklist is it reflect in reporting.And i didn't understand what is the usecase of creating multiple picklist fields. @Guy

Comment: Updated my answer with some additional info. I don't see how your visualforce/apex solution will allow the end users to determine the priority?

Comment: Thanks @Guy. they are asking like to create a dependency with normal picklist. So for example if picklist value is price then multipicklist values have competitor price,add-on price,special packages will available.so need to give prioritize there and want to create reports.@Guy

Comment: ok so the dependency can be handled with dependent picklist. And you mean that within the 2nd picklist (the dependent one) you need the end user to be able to determine an order (so sort the items?)

Comment: Yes. you are right but end user is asking to Concatenate number wise for prioritize view do you have any solutions for this And moreover if i go to visual force.so, painful with multipicklist

Comment: This is not possible with the standard multipicklist functionality, as you've found out as well. So you'll have to go visualforce. But the structure you need to use really depends on how the report should look like in the end. Maybe you can update your question with an exampe report that you need to generate from this.